# Protractor : UnknownError: Chrome failed to start: exited normally (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 platform=Mac OS X 10.10.4 x86_64)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I am trying to run protractor tests on Mac OSX and seeing the following error. My tests work fine with firefox browser

My Configuration:

> NODE : v5.1.0
>
> Protractor Version : 3.0.0
>
> Chrome Browser Version: 47.0.2526.73 (64-bit)
>
> Chromedriver Version: chromedriver_2.20
>
> selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar

```
C02NX03LG3QD:protractor vmukka$ protractor example/conf.js 
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:108
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.4 x86_64)
    at new bot.Error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:108:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/response.js:109:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:160:24
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.goog.defineClass.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:1337:14)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.goog.defineClass.goog.defineClass.abort_.error.executeNext_.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2776:14)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.goog.defineClass.goog.defineClass.abort_.error.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2758:21)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/run.js:124:15)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:379:9)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:157:22)
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:131:30)
    at new Driver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:810:36)
    at [object Object].DirectDriverProvider.getNewDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/direct.js:68:16)
    at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:186:37)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:276:21
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
```

Comment: Do you have chrome installed?

Comment: Yes I do have chrome installed